# IIS 7 - Form post values lost when POSTing to '/' which has a default document (index.aspx)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a asp.net webform that I'm posting to '/' url without a filename, which is transferred to a default document (index.aspx). When running the app pool (.net v4.0) in `Classic` managed pipeline mode, the form values are available to the receiving page. When running in `Integrated` mode, the form values are not available to the page.

**How do I maintain the form collection while in integrated mode when posting to a URL that uses a default document?**

When posting directly to '/index.aspx' there is only 1 request and the form values are retained.
When posting to '/', there are 2 requests. One that I believe is being handled by the `DefaultDocumentModule`, and the second is handled by the page class (ASP.index_aspx).

There is a different handler/module that is handling the second request in integrated mode, that I'm unable to identify.

I'm attempting to identify it during the `Application_EndRequest` event:

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = ((HttpApplication)sender);
    int fieldCount = Request.Form.Count; // there are 5 fields in my POST
    var handler = app.Context.Handler;
}
```

Results:

POST '/'

- Classic mode EndRequest 1
  handler: ASP.index_aspx (System.Web.UI.page)
  fieldCount: 5
- Classic mode EndRequest 2
  handler: System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler
  fieldCount: 5

Form collection **is** available to page.

- Integration mode EndRequest 1
  handler: ASP.index_aspx (System.Web.UI.page)
  fieldCount: 0
- Integration mode EndRequest 2
  **handler: null**
  fieldCount: 5

Form collection **is NOT** available to page.

**Which native module/handler is handling the second request?**

**Update: **

I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228344/postback-doesnt-work-with-aspx-page-as-default-document) to why I was losing the form collection. "Event Handlers Might Not Be Not Raised in a Default Document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode". The `FormControlAdapter` solution given there is working well.

However, I still was not able to identify the module/handler that was handling the request and removing the the posted form collection. I suspected `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` but could not verify. Using the `Application_EndRequest` event, did not give me information on the module, and Advanced Logging doesn't provide information on the Module pipeline either.