# localhost:20980 vs localhost:20980/Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, listview

Listview Insert and Edit buttons work on `localhost:20980/Default.aspx` but does not work on `localhost:20980`. Same happens on production. What makes the difference between the two and what disallows buttons to work with `localhost:20980`?

Breakpoint inside `btnInitInsert_Click()` method stops the execution on `localhost:20980/Default.aspx`, but does not on `localhost:20980`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. [From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228344/postback-doesnt-work-with-aspx-page-as-default-document)

```
public void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Page.Form.Action))
            this.Page.Form.Action = "Default.aspx";
 }
```